# No icons showing in the Start menu on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, icons, start-menu

My start menu icons don't show. They look like the screenshot below. Clearing the icon cache database file and restarting `explorer.exe` doesn't seem to work. Is there another solution?

[image]

Comment: already seen that. none of the fixes in the thread you linked worked...

Comment: There might not be a solution yet, then. Once you have enough rep you can comment there.